# Rails 4 Heroku Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been beating my head against the wall on this all day. For some reason my transition to Rails 4 is not going smoothly.

Everything is working fine locally. I've followed the Railscast example here http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

But, I keep getting "Application Error" messages.

I've converted over to Strong Parameters, removed the initial gem to help with the transition but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'taps'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'meta_request', '~> 0.2.8'
end

gem "rmagick", '2.13.2'
gem "carrierwave"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem 'sidekiq'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.2.1'
  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails"
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 2.2.8'


gem 'rake', '~> 10.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'cancan'

#to have some backward compatability with Rails 3
# gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
# end of backward compatibility section

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

Here are my Heroku logs:

```
2013-09-03T20:22:43.897500+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:22:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:22:43.887029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:22:52.306288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:22:52.396434+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:22:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:22:55.452584+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:22:55.534770+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:22:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:23:17.324857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:23:17.366465+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:23:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:23:43.885269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:23:43.900112+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:23:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:23:52.039503+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:23:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:23:55.651858+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:23:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:23:55.548407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:23:51.946979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:24:17.863662+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:24:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:24:17.793467+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:24:43.898449+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:24:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:24:43.884490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:24:48.210953+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 198.207.185.100 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:24:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 416 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:24:51.895611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:24:51.992038+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:24:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:24:55.447344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:24:55.527892+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:24:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:24:48.211407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="198.207.185.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:25:17.413531+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:25:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:25:17.363609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:25:43.898944+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:25:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:25:43.887741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:25:51.896517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:25:51.993897+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:25:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:25:55.406998+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 198.207.185.100 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:25:55 +0000] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 503 416 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:25:55.465995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:25:55.571885+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:25:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:25:55.400435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/users host=www.clssmi.com fwd="198.207.185.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:26:17.454414+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:26:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:26:17.390242+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:26:38.178541+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-09-03T20:26:48.686733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8682 -e production`
2013-09-03T20:26:49.451948+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-09-03T20:26:50.991236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-03T20:26:50.979390+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-09-03T20:26:51.898087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:26:51.902131+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:26:51.908446+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:26:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:26:51.991956+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:26:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:26:55.462611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:26:55.549889+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:26:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:26:58.966619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-09-03T20:26:58.966885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-09-03T20:27:17.319523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:27:17.356437+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:27:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:27:44.064383+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:27:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:27:44.053392+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:27:51.899592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:27:51.986687+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:27:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:27:52.194673+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle update` by ssipiora@gmail.com
2013-09-03T20:27:55.495248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:27:55.582544+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:27:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:28:07.897649+00:00 heroku[run.7477]: Awaiting client
2013-09-03T20:28:07.919743+00:00 heroku[run.7477]: Starting process with command `bundle update`
2013-09-03T20:28:08.855164+00:00 heroku[run.7477]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-03T20:28:17.380832+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:28:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:28:19.654460+00:00 heroku[run.7477]: Process exited with status 16
2013-09-03T20:28:19.684140+00:00 heroku[run.7477]: State changed from up to complete
2013-09-03T20:28:17.330101+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:28:44.080352+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:28:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:28:51.892936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:28:51.976643+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:28:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:28:55.561761+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:28:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:28:55.478468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:29:17.356915+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:29:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:29:17.323319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:29:44.062134+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:29:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:29:44.050009+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:29:51.992055+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:29:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:29:55.518515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:29:55.603713+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:29:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:29:56.497037+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by ssipiora@gmail.com
2013-09-03T20:29:51.899280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:30:05.046996+00:00 heroku[run.4129]: Awaiting client
2013-09-03T20:30:05.086910+00:00 heroku[run.4129]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-09-03T20:30:06.024911+00:00 heroku[run.4129]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-03T20:30:11.126930+00:00 heroku[run.4129]: Process exited with status 0
2013-09-03T20:30:11.138997+00:00 heroku[run.4129]: State changed from up to complete
2013-09-03T20:30:17.409790+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:30:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:28:44.066322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:30:17.369110+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:30:44.078427+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:30:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:30:44.055949+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:30:51.894906+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:30:51.986891+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:30:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:30:55.503275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:30:55.595770+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.18.57.7 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:30:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:31:17.317989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:31:17.354115+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.31.164.139 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:31:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:31:20.378384+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 198.207.185.100 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:31:20 +0000] "GET /users/index.html HTTP/1.1" 503 416 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:31:44.057924+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:31:44.067149+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 184.73.237.85 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:31:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
2013-09-03T20:31:20.304864+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/users/index.html host=www.clssmi.com fwd="198.207.185.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:31:51.909542+00:00 
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.clssmi.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T20:31:51.996239+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 50.112.95.211 - - [03/Sep/2013:20:31:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 416 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (226624)" www.clssmi.com
```

Everything was working fine this morning. I've double checked DNS and everything seems to be set up fine there too.

I've tried migrating the database and restarting the application. No luck so far.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I know I must be overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions:

> `$ rake rails:update:bin`
>
> This will generate a bin directory in the root of your application.
>   Make sure that it is **NOT** in your .gitignore file, and check this
>   directory and its contents into git.

Have you checked your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Thanks, running the command and redeploying fixed the problem. It wasn't in my .gitignore file. CSS isn't working in production like it does in dev, but I should be able to fix that.